# Unable to Change Display Resolution on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, drivers, intel-graphics

After installing Debian 9.5.0 with Gnome Desktop, I'm unable to change the display resolution through 'Settings'. The only option I have is 1024 x 768. My display's actual resolution is 1280 x 1024. I am using an Intel Core i5-8400 with Intel UHD Graphics 630. I am not using a discrete graphics card. I have tried removing the xserver-xorg-video-intel package and tried adding a new mode using xrandr --newmode but receive a 'Failed to get size of gamma...' error. Are there any drivers I need to install? Is there anything I can do to change the resolution manually? Thanks for any help!

Comment: This https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=264862 leads to this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2377324

Comment: I faced the same issue with kernel version 4.12. Instead of updating the kernel I used the following resources:
- [How to change display resolution settings using xrandr](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html)
AND [xrandr configuring crtc 0 failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136139/xrandr-configure-crtc-0-failed-when-trying-to-change-resolution-on-external-m)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by updating the kernel to version 4.15 or above. I added the stretch-backports source in APT, and then installed the newest kernel version. Versions 4.14 and below do not support Coffee Lake graphics.